# Understanding steps of recursive CTE

Tags: postgresql, recursion, common-table-expression

I am having trouble understanding how recursive CTE works, in terms of the intermediate steps and the working/temporary tables involved along the way.

Slightly adapting the example from [PostgreSQL Documention](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-with.html):

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(n) AS (
    VALUES (1)
  UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM t WHERE n < 5
)
SELECT n FROM t;
```

Running this in Postgres (9.5), I get:

```
 n 
---
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
(5 rows)
```

But why didn't we get more rows? For example

```
    SELECT n+1 FROM t WHERE n < 5
```

when n = 2, why doesn't the table `t` have two rows

```
---
 1
 2
```

and based on that generate

```
---
 2
 3
```

?
If that were the case, the end result should have many duplicate values, such as `2` with the `UNION ALL`.

The relevant part of the documentation says the following about a "working table" and an "intermediate table", which is although descriptive not clear enough to me:

> 1.Evaluate the non-recursive term. ... Include all remaining rows in the result of the recursive query, and also place them in a temporary
>   working table.
>
> 2.So long as the working table is not empty, repeat these steps:
>
> a. Evaluate the recursive term, substituting the current contents of
>   the working table for the recursive self-reference. ... Include all
>   remaining rows in the result of the recursive query, and also place
>   them in a temporary intermediate table.
>
> b. Replace the contents of the working table with the contents of
>   the intermediate table, then empty the intermediate table.

My questions are:

Can anyone please explain step-wise what is going on with the simple example above?

Also, I am trying to understand this recursive CTE from a programming perspective. Can anyone outline a skeleton for the algorithm in the above CTE to generate the sequence?

Comment: Exactly the thing I was wondering thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time the second half of the CTE runs, it sees *only* the results of the previous run. So the initial run executes the top half and yields 1. The second run executes the bottom half. It sees `t` as containing 1, so it returns 2. The third run sees `t` as containing 2 (not 1 and 2, because it only sees the results of the previous run), so it returns 3.

The fourth run sees 3 and returns 4.

The fifth run sees 4 and returns 5.

The sixth run sees 5, but that is excluded by the `WHERE` clause, so it returns no rows. Returning no rows is the signal to stop.

So now the complete result of the CTE is `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, which is what everything *outside* the CTE sees.

Answer (score 3):

A very important statement in the [document](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-with.html#docContent) you referenced clearly gives the reason to your observation.

> **Note**: Strictly speaking, this process is iteration not recursion, but
>   RECURSIVE is the terminology chosen by the SQL standards committee.

In short, `WITH RECURSIVE` evaluation, is ironically *iterative*!

In your example, both the sets (the static set with `1` value & the `SELECT` set with `n` between `2` and `5`) are evaluated only *once*, and most importantly, in a top-down approach.

More so since, the oddity (in naming) came from the SQL standards committee, I doubt you have much leg room, but to understand the 'iterative' nature of the evaluation, despite the wording as 'Recursive'.

Comment: The definition is recursive as the CTE refers to itself. The implementation may be iterative or not.

Comment: I suppose the realised that `SELF REFERENTIAL` would not be a nice keyword.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ but that's the thing: the CTE does not *really* refer to itself, but just to the temporary table created at the previous iteration. You never see results at iteration n-2... It's not recursive!

Comment: @autra the definition is recursive, I don't know how else to write it.. Are you referring to the implementation?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ no, I'm referring to the fact the self-reference is not really a self-reference in my opinion...

Comment: @autra I really don't follow your thought. The definition of CTE is self-referential ... by definition of what self-referential means. As to who sees the results at iteration n-2, why should we care? We see the results at the end, of the whole CTE. The details of the implementations, whether iterative or not, do not matter.

Comment: The CTE (`T` here) is defined as the UNION of two parts (`S` and `R`), where `S` is the first, stable part and `R` is the second part. The `R` in this case refers to `T`, so the CTE's definition is recursive.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ nope. the `R` refers to the previous `R`, not `T` (the aggregation), see the accepted answer.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ this is the confusing part :-)

Comment: @autra The accepted answer refers to the specific implementation, not the definition.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I don't understand what you mean. The way recursive query works is define in the standard right? What I've said is how they are, by definition :-) It's not just an implementation matter

Comment: You said about the accepted answer. That answer explains how the specific (Postgres) implementation works and how the various stages of getting the CTE results do not see all previous stages. This is an implementation detail. The definition of the CTE is self-referential.

Comment: The SQL standard does not specify how the implementations should work. It only specifies the desired results or a query. So an iterative implementation that gives the same results as a recursive one is accepted.

Comment: @autra: You seem to be conflating, not sure whether consciously or not, different kinds of definition. Yes, how recursive CTEs behave is *defined* by the SQL standard. That's one way to understand *definition*. But what I believe @ypercubeᵀᴹ meant was the *definition* of a CTE in a statement in terms of SQL syntax, i.e. it's declaration. If `T` is the name given to a CTE and the body of the CTE references `T`, that means the CTE references itself – as far as the language goes. So by syntactical definition it's recursive, even though by the behaviour it isn't.

Comment: @AndriyM mmhh  I *think* I understand the misunderstanding: I was answering to the very first comment : "the implementation may be iterative or not". No : the implementation is iterative (I'm pretty sure it's specified that way but can't check it of course), and I can show you examples where the results would differ if the implementation specification (what I meant by "by definition") was really recursive. Sorry if I was not precise enough before.