# Recursive CTE on Redshift

Tags: join, amazon-redshift

I have a table that has the following structure with two columns: URL A and URL B. Whenever URL A becomes inactive, it redirects. URL B records that redirect and is otherwise NULL. I now have the issue of having a redirect occur more than 1 times (let's say up to 100 times). I am now trying to assign the value of the last redirect as the unique ID for every URL that ultimately points to the last redirect.

Here is an example:

```
URL-A URL-B
AAA   NULL
AAA   AAB
AAB   NULL
AAB   AAC
AAC   NULL
```

What I want it to look like is this:

```
URL Unique-URL
AAA AAC
AAB AAC
AAC AAC
```

I know that I could probably do this with several joins and subqueries. However, I am not sure how many redirects there might be, possibly up to 100. I understand that you can solve this issue with a recursive CTE on Redshift – however those aren't allowed. What is my alternative?

Comment: I hope there isnt any difference with redsihit. But you need a recursive cte https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979198/understanding-steps-of-recursive-cte

Comment: Hi @JuanCarlosOropeza I found the recursive CTE – apparently that is not usable on Redshift.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid operation: WITH RECURSIVE is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287067/invalid-operation-with-recursive-is-not-supported)

Comment: Not a duplicate – trying to find a solution to a problem that could be solved with recursive CTEs (which don't exist on Redshift). Thanks!

Comment: if you have also ID and timestamp columns to isolate and sort separate chains the individual chain can be collapsed using window functions

Comment: Hi @AlexYes, can you elaborate on that? I do have timestamps and ID columns

Comment: @Julius I've posted a reply. As you see I meant user ID not event ID, hope this won't be a problem

Comment: Recursive CTEs are now supported in Redshift starting April 29th, 2021 using the WITH RECURSIVE syntax so the original approach would now work.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/04/amazon-redshift-announces-support-for-heirarchical-data-queries-with-recursive-cte/ https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html#r_WITH_clause-recursive-cte

Answer (score 1):

Having user ID and timestamp of each event, you can use a window function to determine the last redirect for every user ID and then join it back to the original event table like this:

```
with
redirects_ranked as (
    select user_id,ts,url_a,url_b,row_number() over (partition by user_id order by url_b is null, ts desc)
    from your_table
)
select distinct user_id, t1.url_a, t2.url_b as unique_url
from your_table t1
left join redirects_ranked t2
on t1.user_id=t2.user_id
and t2.row_number=1
```

Comment: You need the last redirect for each URL. So you need some recursive function or loop to find out.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza if every event has the timestamp and user ID the last redirect is just the event with not null `url_b` and greatest timestamp, isn't it? (only if the same user has one chain but for multiple chains session id would work - the whole principle is to replace crawling with ranking)

Comment: You are assuming all url direct on the same finish link, and I don't think that is the case URL_A can end on URL_C but URL_X end on URL_Z, that doesnt have anything to do with time.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yeah, I agree, this is an approximation. Session ID can also be helpful to isolate A to C vs. X to Z, that would leave only cases when there is a mess with paths within the same session. But I think if it's regular browsing most of the cases will be covered by time ranking within user ID (+ session ID) partition and taking the unavailability of recursive CTEs it might be a good enough approximation.

Answer (score 0):

To determine a "last" value you really need a column to order on. Assuming you have a redirect timestamp, so your table really looks like

URL-A URL-B TS

AAA  NULL  2021-05-03

AAA  AAB   2021-06-02

AAB  NULL  2022-03-01

AAB  AAC   2022-04-02

AAC  NULL  2022-05-06

you can use

```
select last_value(ignore nulls URL-B) over (partition by URL-A order by TS) as Unique-URL
```

This should produce the intended result.